# How to mock REST with angular without affecting templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just trying out angular.

I want to get a list of items and show it in template, just hardcoded that now and want to see how it works with ajax. I dont have a rest server working and is trying to mock ajax call.

I just tried including angular mock e2e, but then looks like its covering `get` for templates as well and throws an error `Error: Unexpected request: GET views/main.html`

Is there a simple way I can just mock `REST` requests and have templates work with usual `ajax`?

This is not a unit-test or e2e test scenario, more of a back-end less development. I am doing this on main app and not in testing.

My app.js looks like this

```
'use strict';

var app = angular
.module('sabithangularApp', [
        'ngResource', 'ngMockE2E'
    ]);
app.run(function ($httpBackend) {
    var tasks = [{...},{....},{...}
    ];

    $httpBackend.whenGET('/tasks').respond(tasks);

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/templates\//).passThrough();
    //...
});
```

and error in console looks like

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET views/main.html
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1177:9)
    at sendReq (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7967:9)
    at $http.serverRequest (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7708:16)
    at wrappedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11100:81)
    at wrappedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11100:81)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11186:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12175:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12004:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12279:24)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1382:15
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add an extra line of code (below all other .whenGET()'s) for this that ignores the mock e2e, something like this:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
```

This is a catch-all for any (get) request that is not matched by any other line.

EDIT:

the line below catches all requests starting with 'view/':

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^views\/.*/).passThrough();
```

Comment: hey, thanks, i guess `templates` should be `views` now

Comment: @sabithpocker, try the updated answer. And if that doesn't work, you are probably better of having this catch-all rule anyway

Comment: will try it, its issue with the regex i was using, let me try yours. Because when i type in the exact url instead of regex, it was working. Couldnt check this as i was traveling

Answer (score 0):

As I know you need to use [$httpBackend](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend) for testing.

Comment: No, it is designed to be used for testing OR for backend-less development.
« $httpBackend - service in module ngMockE2E: Fake HTTP backend implementation suitable for end-to-end testing or backend-less development of applications that use the $http service.» See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend